# UEFI mixup with previous windows 10 disk on Lenovo

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a lenovo laptop that originally had one disk with windows 10 using UEFI.
I decided to replace the HDD with an SSD. Additionally, I replaced my DVD-ROM with an adaptor and put my older windows 10 HDD in there.

I installed linux on the SSD (with the second drive removed) and everything worked fine (UEFI mode). However, when I slide in the second disk, the computer goes into an infinite reboot loop as if it is trying to load from the 2nd drive.

I am only able to boot successfully by pressing the novo button and manually selecting a disk.

However, if I remove the second drive (holding windows 10), everyting works fine. I have tried changing the priority in the bios for UEFI boot order but it makes no difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I also tried the utility boot-repair but no luck. Booting from the novo button all the time doesn't seem to be a solution as it's a good way to break that button.

### Update

Here is the report from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14298897/

Is there a chance I could delete the EFI partition from the second disk and solve my problem in that manner?

### Update 2 - tried again

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14299360/

Comment: I am sorely tempted to switch completely to bios using something like https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-convert-windows-8-from-bios-to-uefi/

Comment: Finally, another semi-solution I am thinking about would be: A) Erase the SSD, B) Switch to legacy mode (BIOS), C) Install windows first, and then linux on SSD. Switching to legacy mode allows the computer to boot fine if an OS with a legacy bootloader exists. I would then rarely use the old windows 10 HDD except through the novo button and as data storage.

Comment: Not sure if it will show anything or not: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
 Many with DVD caddy as drive have various issues. Many are not configured as a boot able device or are not standard as internal nor external drives.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a disk caddy to the optical bay caused an old HP laptop to lock-up too at any grub access to the new disk.  BIOS put the new disk before the internal disk for the "hdd" boot item -- only workaround for me was to boot off a USB with higher boot order than the hard disk(s). The new disk then worked fine.

Comment: Any way to put the boot menu on a usb stick? sticks with UEFI seem to boot fine.